# How to send selected object details from one selection to another in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I need help to build a dynamic user interface based on the selection that user makes.
I have tab-delimited file which the R sever script reads, this file contains 5 columns of data (Job_Types, Job_Order, Task_Number, Activity_Number, Activity_Type)
Here is how the data table would look like
Completed   JO_1    JO_1_TN_1   JO_1_TN_1_AN_1  Drawing
Completed   JO_1    JO_1_TN_2   JO_1_TN_2_AN_1  Drawing
Completed   JO_1    JO_1_TN_3   JO_1_TN_3_AN_2  Cutting
Completed   JO_1    JO_1_TN_4   JO_1_TN_4_AN_1  Drawing
Current JO_2    JO_2_TN_1   JO_2_TN_1_AN_1  Drawing
Current JO_2    JO_2_TN_2   JO_2_TN_2_AN_2  Cutting
Current JO_3    JO_3_TN_1   JO_3_TN_1_AN_3  Painting

Here is the challenge I am currently facing:
The user is provided an interface (pull-down menu) to select Job_Types, based on the Job_Types selected by the user the Job_Order Pull-down menu gets populated, now I want to populate the next pull-down menu of selection of Task_Number based on the Job_Order selection that the user makes, on similar lines I would want to provide the user the Activity_Number selection based on the Task_Number selection the user makes.
E.g: Say User Selects "Current" (Job_Types) from the first pull-down menu. 
The second Pull-down menu should have only JO_2 and JO_3 listed as option to select; now lets say user selects "JO_2 and JO_3"
The third Pull-down menu should have only  JO_2_TN_1, JO_2_TN_2, JO_3_TN_1 Task number listed for selection, say the user selects "JO_2_TN_1, JO_3_TN_1"
The Fourth Pull-down menu should have only JO_3_TN_1_AN_3 as options

Here is my code
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

```
data1 <- data.frame(read.table("Data.txt", sep="\t", header=TRUE))
                            # reactiveValues(current_col = 0)   
output$mytext <- renderText({
    result <- input$var
```

})
    output$choose_Job_Types <- renderUI({
                                    if ("SelectJobType" %in% input$var)
                                    {
                                        com <- paste(" ")
                                        selectInput("JobOrder", "Select Job Order", com)
                                    }
                                    else if ("Current" %in% input$var)
                                    {
                                        sub_data <- subset(data1, data1[,1] %in% "Current", select=c("Job_Order"))
                                        selectInput("JobOrder", "Select Job Order", sub_data[,1], multiple=TRUE)

```
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    sub_data <- subset(data1, data1[,1] %in% "Completed", select=c("Job_Order"))
                                    selectInput("JobOrder", "Select Job Order", sub_data[,1], multiple=TRUE)
                                }

                            })


output$choose_Job_Order <- renderUI({
                                    sub_data2 <- subset(data1, data1[,2] %in% output$JobOrder, select=c("Task_Number"))
                                    selectInput("TaskNumber", "Select Task Number", sub_data2[,2], multiple=TRUE)                                   
                                })  
}
```

)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel(strong("Workflow Visualize Model", style="color:black"), windowTitle="WorkFlow"),

sidebarPanel(

tags$head(
        tags$style(type='text/css', "input { width: 100px; }"),# control numericInput box        ,
        tags$style(type='text/css', "select,textarea,.jslider,.well { background-color: #F0F0F0; } ")
        ),

```
selectInput("var", 
  label = (strong("Choose Job Types", style="color:black")),
  choices = c("SelectJobType","Current","Completed"),
  selected = "SelectJobType"),
     uiOutput("choose_Job_Types"),
     uiOutput("choose_Job_Order"),
       br()
),

mainPanel(  
        tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Introduction", (h1("Current Status Overview Of Jobs in Pipeline")),
        textOutput("mytext"),


                plotOutput("graph_report")

        ),
        tabPanel("TablularView", (h1("Tabular View of Selected Job Orders")), tableOutput("DataTable"))
    )
)
```

))

Comment: I think I solved the challenge.
To call selection values of one selected object in a new selected objects I found I prefix the LabelID of the previous selection object with the input$ and it works.